# Determine the numbers a, b and c such that it satisfies the condition

Tags: calculus, tangent-line, secant

I have a function $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx+ c$ and I need to solve for the numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$. The numbers need to satisfy the following condition:

The slope of the secant line defined by points $P = (0, 1)$ and $Q = (1, 0)$, both on the graph of $f$, is the slope of the tangent line of $f$ at $x = 1 + \frac1{\sqrt{3}}$.

The wording of this question has me confused on how to find the solution. Any help would be great!

Comment: What information about $a,b,c$ do you get from the assumption that $P$ is on the graph? What information do you get from $Q$ being on the graph? What expression involving $a,b,c$ equals the slope of the tangent line to the graph at $x=1+\frac1{\sqrt3}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$$
$$P=(0,1)\Rightarrow f(0)=1\Rightarrow c=1$$
$$Q=(1,0)\Rightarrow f(1)=0\Rightarrow 1+a+b+c=0\Rightarrow a+b=-2$$
now we are told that the secant line passes through both of these points. We know:
$$f'(x)=3x^2+2ax+b$$
$$\text{grad secant}=\frac{0-1}{1-0}=-1$$
and we are told that
$$\text{grad secant}=\text{grad tangent}$$
also we know by definition that:
$$\text{grad tangent}\times f'=-1$$
and so we get:
$$f'\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)=1$$
going back to our equation from before:
$$1=f'\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)=3\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)^2+2a\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)+b$$
now we have a system of equations:
$$\begin{pmatrix}2a\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1-3\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)^2\\-2\end{pmatrix}$$
which can be solved for $a,b$ and we already know $c$